# White space padding in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, css, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to display image in `WebBrowser` control with this code:

```
string captcha = "<img src=\"http://www.reddit.com/captcha/{0}/.png\" border=\"0\"></img>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Format(captcha, iden);
```

but it looks like this. Look at only the top image. There is white space on top-left and image is moved down-right.

[image]

I have tried `border=0; padding=0; vertical-align:top;` inside img and body tag and nothing works.

Is there a way to remove that space?

Comment: How about using those neat web developer tools, built into IE, Chrome or Firefox to inspect the reason for the white-space?

Comment: BTW: Are you writing a tool to spam reddit?

Comment: I don't know how to use those tools on app. How do u do that? No, I don't plan to spam. This is for resetting the badge from two reddits.

Comment: To start simple, I would _not_ show the string inside the webbrowser control but inside an external browser. E.g. on showing it in the form, you might also write it to a temporary HTML file and ShellExecute that file to fire up your default browser. Then, use the developer tools there.

Comment: yes, I see now what do you mean. No need now, the Sam answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <html> and <body> elements have padding/margins. Try this:

```
string captcha = "<style>html, body {{ padding: 0; margin: 0 }}</style><img src=\"http://www.reddit.com/captcha/{0}/.png\" border=\"0\"></img>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Format(captcha, iden);
```

Comment: It gives FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format" for the second line in my case, but it's working when I use string without formatting. Probably because of curly braces?

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the string.Format. I've updated it so the braces are escaped now.

Comment: Indeed, it's important to add the style not only to the body but also to the *html* tag ! That did the trick for me.